# Как в PHP изменить последний элемент массива?

Tags: массивы, php

Предположим, есть массив PHP, в котором постоянно меняется количество элементов, нужно просто взять и изменить значение последнего элемента.

Сейчас я делаю это так:

```
$array[count($array)-1] = "123";
```

Нельзя ли как-то это делать проще?

Что-то типа:

```
end($array) = "123";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
array_pop($array);
array_push($array, '123');
```

upd. уииииииииииии

```
array_splice($array, -1, 1, '123');
```

upd2. теперь в одно выражение!

```
array_pop($array) xor array_push($array, '123');
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php

Comment: Красавчег! Просьба добавлять ссылки на офф.документацию для ускорения поиска описания функций.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант 1:

```
function endKey($array){
    end($array);
    return key($array);
}

$a = array("one" => "apple", "two" => "orange", "three" => "pear");
$a[endKey($a)] = "new";
```

Вариант 2:

```
$a = array("one" => "apple", "two" => "orange", "three" => "pear");
array_pop($a);
$a["three"] = "new";
```

[Мануал(php.net/array)](http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.array.php) Вам в помощь.

Кстати, Ваш вариант подойдёт только для массивов с числовыми индексами, которые отличаются на единицу.

Answer (score -1):

Чем вас не устроил этот вариант? Проще уже некуда. Напишите свою функцию:

```
function change_last_item(&$arr, $val) {
    $arr[count($arr)-1] = $val;
}
change_last_item($array, "123");
```

или

```
function arr_cli(&$arr, $val) {
    end($arr);
    $arr[key($arr)] = $val;
    reset($arr);
}
arr_cli($array, "123");
```

или используйте ООП и работайте с объектом как с массивом:

```
// реализацию писать больше, смотрите, читайте про итераторы
$array->setLastItem("123");
```

Comment: огромный велосипед

Comment: @Shrek, что конкретно не устраивает?